# While new user is trying to opening database,getting error"your address book does not contain any cross certificates capable of authenticating server"

Tags: lotus-notes

While new user is trying to open the database,user is getting error " your address book does not contain any cross certificates capable of authenticating server"

Answer (score 0):

In this case the user does not use the ID vault that you generated for him but an ID that the client generated itself because it did not have access to the Domino server during setup. Give the user the right ID file and it will work.